# Configuring NLB for SharePoint 2010

Tags: load-balancing, sharepoint-2010

How can I configure Network Load Balancing for multiple SharePoint 2010 web servers?

I googled and binged and there are not many resources I could find on doing this for SharePoint 2010.

Can anyone point me to some useful resouces? I am pretty new to the IT Pro side of SharePoint - any general guidelines would also be useful.

Comment: are you looking for software or hardware solutions?

Answer (score 1):

See here for the [Network Load Balancing Deployment Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc754833%28WS.10%29.aspx).  And specific to SharePoint 2010 see here:
[SharePoint 2010 Network Load Balancing](http://imperfectit.blogspot.com/2010/09/sharepoint-2010-network-load-balancing.html). You have to configure the the NLB nodes to use Multicast mode, that seems to be the conclusion.